# Referencing Column Index Value In Formula

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, cbind

I am looking to make this more concise.  I want one matrix "mat" that has binary data values (0,1) that are returned based on a probability.  Currently I have created each column individually and will use `cbind` for create the final matrix:

```
mat1=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1), 100, 1) 
mat2=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/2), 100, 1) 
mat3=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/3), 100, 1)
mat4=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/4), 100, 1)
mat5=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/5), 100, 1)
mat6=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/6), 100, 1)
mat7=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/7), 100, 1)
mat8=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/8), 100, 1)
mat9=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/9), 100, 1)
mat10=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/10), 100, 1)
```

However the probabilities can be determined by the function 1/k where k is the column index default number, but I am not sure how to reference the column index.  How is it possible to simplify this? Is it possible to use a function to account for all this repetition (ie. k=k+1...).

Comment: `sapply(1:10, function(x) rbinom(100, 1, 1/x))`?

Comment: Brilliant that worked! I have only been using R a week and I spent like 4 hours trying to figure this out, embarrassingly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use a for-loop as a "quick and dirty"-solution:

```
# setting seed for comparison later on
# set.seed(1111)

# preparing an empty vector
out<-c()

# for-loop
for (k in 1:10){
  out<-c(out, rbinom(100,1,1/k))
}
out<-matrix(out, 100, 10)
```

Here, k is one in the first iteration, it is two in the second and so on. Everything is stored in one vector called out. The matrix-function fills the matrix by columns per default. Thus, out is a 100*10 matrix, and each column belongs to one value of k.

To prove that it results in the exact same matrix as your approach:

```
set.seed(1111)
mat1=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1), 100, 1) 
mat2=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/2), 100, 1) 
mat3=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/3), 100, 1)
mat4=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/4), 100, 1)
mat5=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/5), 100, 1)
mat6=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/6), 100, 1)
mat7=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/7), 100, 1)
mat8=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/8), 100, 1)
mat9=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/9), 100, 1)
mat10=matrix(rbinom(100,1,1/10), 100, 1) 
mat<-cbind(mat1,mat2, mat3,mat4,mat5,mat6,mat7,mat8,mat9,mat10)

identical(mat, out)
```

The identical-function should testify that the for-loop does the same. However, there might be as many other ways to do this as there are R-Programmers.

You might find the R-Package "swirl" useful. It teaches you interactively how to perform such tasks!

Edit: Okay, I was too late. NRussell already gave a better (in terms of shorter code, better performance) answer in the comments ;)

Comment: Thanks very much!